# Can i retrieve array value not using loop?

Tags: php

is there a way to retrieve array value not using any loop function?
I have this sort of array

```
$at=array(
    array(
        array('Title:','titl','s','c',$titles),
        array('First Name:','name','i','A',2,10 ),
    ),
```

Comment: first one can be accessed via $at[0][0], et cetera

Comment: You mean $at[0], or $at[0][0]? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Can you tell me how you want the output to be.?

Comment: function work($s){ global $at;foreach($at[$s] as $v){echo $v[1];} via this code i can get the whole values out of $at and can use $v[1] in my switch and anyother function i need but now i want to have this whole list of array values like (title name and so on) without using foreach loop i cannot use $at[1][0] as i have a long bunch of array

Answer (score 1):

try [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Sorry this one was suppose to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like it's probably one level too deep, but to directly work with a more basic example:

```
$at=array( array('Title:','titl','s','c',$titles), array('First Name:','name','i','A',2,10 )

list($title, $something, $foo, $bar) = current($at);

echo $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

for example $at[0], $at[1], $at[2]

When an array hasn't been assigned keys, the keys ( in the above example keys would be 0 1 and 2) ascend numerically from 0.

For an array with keys (such as `$at = array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2')` ), you can access the properties as $at['key'], $at['key2'] ( note the quotes wrapping the key name )

Hope this is of use to you!

Cheers!, 
Pedro

Comment: function work($s){ global $at;foreach($at[$s] as $v){echo $v[1];} via this code i can get the whole values out of $at and can use $v[1] in my switch and anyother function i need but now i want to have this whole list of array values like (title name and so on) without using foreach loop i cannot use $at[1][0] as i have a long bunch of array

Answer (score 0):

you need to know the key of the value you want to select

```
  echo $at[0];
  echo $at[0][0];
  echo $at[0][3];
```